# Can I save a serialized array to database, that has some reference sub arrays?

Tags: php, serialization, reference

The PHP code I am interating through is as follows for the Update process:

```
$data = $_POST;
foreach ($data['answers'] as &$d):
    if(!isset($d['default'])):
       $d['default'] = "false";
    endif;
endforeach;
```

And when I var_dump it after that iteration, I get the following:

```
array(2) {
  ["question"]=>
  string(20) "Which did you like?"
  ["answers"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["default"]=>
      string(4) "true"
      ["option"]=>
      string(5) "First"
    }
    [1]=>
    &array(2) {
      ["option"]=>
      string(5) "Second"
      ["default"]=>
      string(5) "false"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the second array has "**&array**" keyword, I am assuming that's implying a reference. My question is, can I serialize this array and save it into MYSQL DB? I was getting some data error on the display page after, so I want to make sure if this has anything to do with this.

**UPDATE**
Error message I get on the display page is that
***Undefined index: option***

Comment: Post the error and the code that's generating it.

Comment: Okay posted it, but it's not saving the option key.

Comment: Actually, here's note on the `serialize()` parameters from the docs: "The value to be serialized. serialize() handles all types, except the resource-type. You can even serialize() arrays that contain references to itself. Circular references inside the array/object you are serializing will also be stored. **Any other reference will be lost**."

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks, I think the problem is somewhere else. I would look into it. =)

Comment: @Sammitch Please post that as an answer, so I can accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php):

> serialize() handles all types, except the resource-type. You can even serialize() arrays that contain references to itself. Circular references inside the array/object you are serializing will also be stored. **Any other reference will be lost**.

Answer (score 1):

About yout error message, post the line youre calling the "option" index, so we can see what is going wrong...

And as Sammitch said, you can use serialize() to store this data in your DB.